# Why nginx doesn't recognize subdomain conf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, domain-name-system, subdomain

I created a config for my subdomain, but it is not working. I literally copied domain.conf and renamed to sub.domain.conf and then inside the config renamed the server names and pathings from domain.com to sub.domain.com and it is not working. And if you do `ls` in sites-enabled dir you get to see that the subdomain conf is in red. What does it mean? `nginx -t` gives no errors.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXj5q.png]

I managed to make subdomain work if I enter its own server block inside main domain.conf, but I want to have separate config file for subdomain because it's going to run cms platform and it contains lots of other configs and going to do that for lots of multiple subdomains, and squeezing all of them into same main domain.conf is simply impractical.

Comment: Often the configuration files in `sites-enabled` are symbolically linked to originals in `sites-available`. The command `nginx -T` will test the configuration **and** let you see what `nginx` is actually using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, a light blue color in the output of `ls` means a symbolic link and a red color means a broken symbolic link. It seems to me that you have a broken symlink and that's why your subdomain is not working.

You need to copy and edit the original files not the symlinks. Do your changes to the files under `sites-available`. The `sites-enabled` directory is just a collection of symlinks to the enabled config.